# Suggestions for an Authenticated Web Form solution

Tags: web-services, forms

I am tasked with creating a web form for people to update their details. I have existing data which I need to authenticate users against to make sure we are updating the correct person. I get the feeling that if I code this from scratch I will be reinventing the wheel.

I'm looking either for an online survey solution like SurveyMonkey (but not SurveyMonkey as it does no have automatic authentication) or a web form system that I can install and configure.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I need to build my own.

I will code in PHP and use a MySQL database. The login screen will take three bits of information, which if found in a record in the database, will show the user a screen with their old data, and a form for updating this data. They enter their new data and hit submit which will put their information into another table in the database.

Nothing to hard but I'd rather use a pre-made system which is already debugged and comes with with some built in tools so the users can manipulate the data.